# How Can I Get Reward Video To work On cordova-plugin-admob-free?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

I successfully display real admob banner & interstitial ads with cordova-plugin-admob-free by placing `onClick="admob.interstitial.show()"` event in single-page document of my jquery mobile app but fail to get `onClick="admob.rewardvideo.show()"` to work unless I put `id="showAd"` within `<a>` attribute but that only work with the first `<a>` of all `<a id="showAd">` attributes I put.

**Is there codes I can put in my html document to get Admob Rewarded Video to work on cordova-plugin-admob-free?**

This works : `<a onClick="admob.interstitial.show(); ExitApp()" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="delete" class="ui-btn-left">Close</a>`

This doesn't work : `<a href="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5FDr8fLVGjRTWRCOWEwNC04TVU" data-role="button" onClick="admob.rewardvideo.show()">Download PDF</a>`

These are codes inside basic.js that I included in my html :

```
    var admobid = {}
    if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {  // for android & amazon-fireos
      admobid = {
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712',
      }
    } else if (/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {  // for ios
      admobid = {
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910',
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      admob.banner.config({
        id: admobid.banner,
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: true,
      })
      admob.banner.prepare()

      admob.interstitial.config({
        id: admobid.interstitial,
        isTesting: true,
        autoShow: false,
      })
      admob.interstitial.prepare()

      document.getElementById('showAd').disabled = true
      document.getElementById('showAd').onclick = function() {
        admob.interstitial.show()
      }

    }, false)

    document.addEventListener('admob.banner.events.LOAD_FAIL', function(event) {
      console.log(event)
    })

    document.addEventListener('admob.interstitial.events.LOAD_FAIL', function(event) {
      console.log(event)
    })

    document.addEventListener('admob.interstitial.events.LOAD', function(event) {
      console.log(event)
      document.getElementById('showAd').disabled = false
    })

    document.addEventListener('admob.interstitial.events.CLOSE', function(event) {
      console.log(event)

      admob.interstitial.prepare()
    })
```

And these are from mediation.js :

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      admob.rewardvideo.config({
        id: 'ca-app-pub-5123658954256325/6485882531',
        isTesting: false,
        autoShow: false,
      })
      admob.rewardvideo.prepare()

      document.getElementById('showAd').disabled = true
      document.getElementById('showAd').onclick = function() {
        admob.rewardvideo.show()
      }
    }, false)

    document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.LOAD_FAIL', function(event) {
      console.log(event)
    })

    document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.LOAD', function(event) {
      console.log(event)
      document.getElementById('showAd').disabled = false
    })

    document.addEventListener('admob.rewardvideo.events.CLOSE', function(event) {
      console.log(event)

      admob.rewardvideo.prepare()
    })
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You want to show a video and be able to download a document at the same time?

Comment: All I want is a code to get video ads showing anywhere I put the code. Especially, I also want video ads showing before user be able to download document.

Comment: The reason why the second link does not work is because it's trying to navigate to the URL (the `href` does this) and show the video at the same time. It can only do one. If you want to be able to show the video in more than one element, add `$('.showAd').click(function() {admob.rewardvideo.show();}` in your code, then simply add `class="showAd"` on any HTML element you want to trigger the video.

Comment: No luck with class Sir even after I removed the href. It could only be done by id.

Comment: @JM-AGMS I meant I could show interstitial ads with onclick function at same time it navigates to href `<a href="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5FDr8fLVGjRTWRCOWEwNC04TVU" data-role="button" onClick="admob.interstitial.show()">Download PDF</a>`but not with video ads `<a href="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5FDr8fLVGjRTWRCOWEwNC04TVU" data-role="button" onClick="admob.rewardvideo.show()">Download PDF</a>`